# Sales commission calculator

Tags: python, automation, calculator

I'm trying to create a sales commission calculator. These are the roles:

```
Tiers |       Amount        | Percentage applied
  1   | £84,000 - £98,000   | 7.50%
  2   | £98,000 - £112,000  | 10.00%
  3   | £112,000 - £126,000 | 12%
  4   | £126,000- £146,000  | 15.00%

minimum amount= 84k
```

This is my code, but it doesn't return any value

```
from bisect import bisect

rates = [0, 7.5, 10, 12, 15]   


brackets = [84000,        # first 84k
            98000,        # next  14k
            112000,       # next  14k
            126000,       # next  14k
            146000]       # next  20k


base_tax = [0,            # 84k * 0%
            14000,        # 14k * 7.5%
            14000,        # 14k * 7.5% + 14000
            14000,        # 14k * 7.5% + 14000 + 14000
            20000]        # 20k * 15% + 14000 + 14000 + 14000

income = 120000

def tax(income):
    i = bisect(brackets, income)
    if not i:
        return 0
    rate = rates[i]
    bracket = brackets[i-1]
    income_in_bracket = income - bracket
    tax_in_bracket = income_in_bracket * rate / 100
    total_tax = base_tax[i-1] + tax_in_bracket

    return total_tax
```

How can I implement an automatic calculator that takes into account the ratios and the different tires?

Answer (score 0):

- First, you haven't imported the module which contains bisect function.
- Secondly, in order to return value, the function should be called. You have to call that function. So, you have to do following things:

Add `import bisect` at the starting of the code.

In `i = bisect(brackets, income)`, you have to write `i = bisect.bisect(brackets, income)`. It's the way to use bisect function of bisect module. The general way of using function of any module is `module.function()`.

To print tax, write `print(total_tax)` before return code. You haven't written that.

And, at last call the function by adding: `tax(income)`

P.S. Sorry for this way because the code was not getting formatted properly. Hope you understand.